# Hide show markers based on dropdown select value google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

when I changed the value from the drop-down. it shows new markers simultaneously with the old one. How I can fix it

```
enter code here

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <select class="form-control" name="" id="business">
                <option value="0">A</option>
                <option value="1">B</option>
                <option value="2">C</option>
                <option value="3">D</option>
                <option value="4">E</option> 
                <option value="5">F</option>
                <option value="6">G</option>
                <option value="7">H</option>
                <option value="8">I</option>
            </select>
            <div id="map"></div>
           </body>
       </html>
```

fiddle here
https://jsfiddle.net/gfbejwz8/5/

this is the complete js code (copied from fiddle):

```
var locations = [
  ['Kabul', 34.5539097, 69.0576492, 16],
  ['Tirana', 41.3310131, 19.8003137, 16],
  ['Algiers', 36.7538302, 3.0556523, 16],
  ['Andorra la Vella', 42.5050929, 1.5159882, 16],
  ['Luanda', -8.8534459, 13.2490852, 16]
];

var locations1 = [
  ['Saint Johns', 47.4820582, -52.9677822, 16],
  ['Buenos Aires', -34.6156625, -58.5033376, 16],
  ['Yerevan', 40.1535005, 44.4185278, 16],
  ['Canberra', -35.2812958, 149.124822, 16],
  ['Vienna', 48.220778, 16.3100208, 16]
];

var locations2 = [
  ['baku', 40.3947021, 49.7849203, 16],
  ['Nassau', 25.0326342, -77.4421124, 16],
  ['Manama', 26.2266541, 50.5715166, 16],
  ['Dhaka', 23.7807777, 90.3492863, 16],
  ['Bridgetown', 13.1013529, -59.6140472, 16]
];

var locations3 = [
  ['Minsk', 53.8840092, 27.5796488, 16],
  ['Brussels', 50.8387874, 4.2933659, 16],
  ['Belmopan', 17.25488, -88.7825991, 16],
  ['Porto Novo', 6.4959937, 2.6047896, 16],
  ['Thimphu', 27.4794738, 89.603376, 16]
];

// 4
var locations4 = [
  ['Sucre', -19.0205659, -65.2948115, 16],
  ['Sarajevo', 43.8937798, 18.3479722, 16],
  ['Gaborone', -24.6091349, 25.8604651, 16],
  ['Brasília', -15.7215857, -48.0073973, 16],
  ['Bandar Seri Begawan', 4.9062259, 114.903071, 16]
];

var locations5 = [
  ['Sofia', 42.6389981, 23.2539075, 16],
  ['Ouagadougou', 12.3585737, -1.5718626, 16],
  ['Bujumbura', -3.3752144, 29.3203635, 16],
  ['Phnom Penh', 11.579524,104.8201472, 16],
  ['Yaounde', 3.8304736, 11.4404136, 16]
];

var locations6 = [
  ['Ottawa', 45.2502975, -76.0804292, 16],
  ['Bangui', 4.3783071, 18.5421798, 16],
  ['Santiago', -33.4533303, -70.6967031, 16],
  ['Beijing', 39.9390628, 116.2573775, 16],
  ['Bogota', 4.6484652, -74.1778466, 16]
];

var locations7 = [
  ['Moroni', -11.7009062, 43.2411225, 16],
  ['San Jose', 9.63482, -84.2767228, 16],
  ['Zagreb', 45.8402941, 15.8942924, 16],
  ['Havana', 23.0508292, -82.4030415, 16],
  ['Nicosia', 35.1923177, 33.3623829, 16]
];

var locations8 = [
  ['Prague', 50.0597588, 14.3955848, 16],
  ['Copenhagen', 55.6713108, 12.5588047, 16],
  ['Roseau', 15.3061008, -61.3860845, 16],
  ['Paris', 48.8589101, 2.3120407, 16],
  ['Amman', 31.8359753, 35.8075489, 16]
];

var map;
var markers = [];

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.0595581, 31.22344),
        scrollwheel: false,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: [
            {elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#a2bccc'}]},
            {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#242f3e'}]},
            {elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#ffffff'}]},
            {
              featureType: 'administrative.locality',
              elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'poi',
              elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'poi.park',
              elementType: 'geometry',
              stylers: [{color: '#263c3f'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'poi.park',
              elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#6b9a76'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'road',
              elementType: 'geometry',
              stylers: [{color: '#38414e'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'road',
              elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
              stylers: [{color: '#ffffff'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'road',
              elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#ffffff'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'road.highway',
              elementType: 'geometry',
              stylers: [{color: '#746855'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'road.highway',
              elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
              stylers: [{color: '#ffffff'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'road.highway',
              elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#ffffff'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'transit',
              elementType: 'geometry',
              stylers: [{color: '#ffffff'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'transit.station',
              elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#ffffff'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'water',
              elementType: 'geometry',
              stylers: [{color: '#1a5477'}]
            },
            {
              featureType: 'water',
              elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
              stylers: [{color: '#5285a5'}]
            },
          ]
    });

    var num_markers = locations.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < num_markers; i++) {
        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {
                lat: locations[i][1],
                lng: locations[i][2]
            },
            map: map,
            html: locations[i][0],
            id: i,
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function () {
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                id: this.id,
                content: this.html,
                position: this.getPosition(),

            });
            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, 'closeclick', function () {
                markers[this.id].setVisible(true);

            });
            this.setVisible(false);
            infowindow.open(map);
        });
    }

}


//Setting Location with jQuery
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#business").on('change', function() {

        if (this.value == '0') {

            var num_markers = locations.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < num_markers; i++) {
                markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {
                        lat: locations[i][1],
                        lng: locations[i][2]
                    },
                    map: map,
                    html: locations[i][0],
                    id: i,
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function () {
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        id: this.id,
                        content: this.html,
                        position: this.getPosition()
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, 'closeclick', function () {
                        markers[this.id].setVisible(true);
                    });
                    this.setVisible(false);
                    infowindow.open(map);
                });
            }
        }

        if (this.value == '1') {
            var num_markers1 = locations1.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < num_markers1; i++) {
                markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {
                        lat: locations1[i][1],
                        lng: locations1[i][2]
                    },
                    map: map,
                    html: locations1[i][0],
                    id: i,
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function () {
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        id: this.id,
                        content: this.html,
                        position: this.getPosition()
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, 'closeclick', function () {
                        markers[this.id].setVisible(true);
                    });
                    this.setVisible(false);
                    infowindow.open(map);
                });
            }
        }

        if (this.value == '2') {
            var num_markers2 = locations2.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < num_markers2; i++) {
                markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {
                        lat: locations2[i][1],
                        lng: locations2[i][2]
                    },
                    map: map,
                    html: locations2[i][0],
                    id: i,
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function () {
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        id: this.id,
                        content: this.html,
                        position: this.getPosition()
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, 'closeclick', function () {
                        markers[this.id].setVisible(true);
                    });
                    this.setVisible(false);
                    infowindow.open(map);
                });
            }
        }

        if (this.value == '3') {
            var num_markers3 = locations3.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < num_markers3; i++) {
                markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {
                        lat: locations3[i][1],
                        lng: locations3[i][2]
                    },
                    map: map,
                    html: locations3[i][0],
                    id: i,
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function () {
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        id: this.id,
                        content: this.html,
                        position: this.getPosition()
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, 'closeclick', function () {
                        markers[this.id].setVisible(true);
                    });
                    this.setVisible(false);
                    infowindow.open(map);
                });
            }
        }

        if (this.value == '4') {
            var num_markers4 = locations4.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < num_markers4; i++) {
                markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {
                        lat: locations4[i][1],
                        lng: locations4[i][2]
                    },
                    map: map,
                    html: locations4[i][0],
                    id: i,
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function () {
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        id: this.id,
                        content: this.html,
                        position: this.getPosition()
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, 'closeclick', function () {
                        markers[this.id].setVisible(true);
                    });
                    this.setVisible(false);
                    infowindow.open(map);
                });
            }
        }

        if (this.value == '5') {
            var num_markers5 = locations5.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < num_markers5; i++) {
                markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {
                        lat: locations5[i][1],
                        lng: locations5[i][2]
                    },
                    map: map,
                    html: locations5[i][0],
                    id: i,
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function () {
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        id: this.id,
                        content: this.html,
                        position: this.getPosition()
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, 'closeclick', function () {
                        markers[this.id].setVisible(true);
                    });
                    this.setVisible(false);
                    infowindow.open(map);
                });
            }
        }

        if (this.value == '6') {
            var num_markers6 = locations6.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < num_markers6; i++) {
                markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {
                        lat: locations6[i][1],
                        lng: locations6[i][2]
                    },
                    map: map,
                    html: locations6[i][0],
                    id: i,
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function () {
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        id: this.id,
                        content: this.html,
                        position: this.getPosition()
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, 'closeclick', function () {
                        markers[this.id].setVisible(true);
                    });
                    this.setVisible(false);
                    infowindow.open(map);
                });
            }
        }

        if (this.value == '7') {
            var num_markers7 = locations7.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < num_markers7; i++) {
                markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {
                        lat: locations7[i][1],
                        lng: locations7[i][2]
                    },
                    map: map,
                    html: locations7[i][0],
                    id: i,
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function () {
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        id: this.id,
                        content: this.html,
                        position: this.getPosition()
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, 'closeclick', function () {
                        markers[this.id].setVisible(true);
                    });
                    this.setVisible(false);
                    infowindow.open(map);
                });
            }
        }

        if (this.value == '8') {
            var num_markers8 = locations8.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < num_markers8; i++) {
                markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {
                        lat: locations8[i][1],
                        lng: locations8[i][2]
                    },
                    map: map,
                    html: locations8[i][0],
                    id: i,
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function () {
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        id: this.id,
                        content: this.html,
                        position: this.getPosition()
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, 'closeclick', function () {
                        markers[this.id].setVisible(true);
                    });
                    this.setVisible(false);
                    infowindow.open(map);
                });
            }
        }



    });

});
```

Comment: You need to provide JavaScript code to get a useful answer. The markup alone gives no indication of what could be functionally wrong.

Comment: Please check the fiddle. Your help will be highly appreciated https://jsfiddle.net/gfbejwz8/5/

Comment: A fiddle is fine, but will not help anyone in the future as it is likely to change. You should bring the javascript into the question to archive it for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is remove old markers everytime you create any.

```
...
$("#business").on('change', function() {
    if(markers)   //if any exist, remove them from map, and reset array
    {
           markers.forEach(function(marker){
                   marker.setMap(null);
           });
           markers =[];
    }
...
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/63f259ja/